# GTX1080 no video after installing GPUTweakII

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, pci-express

So as the title says I installed GPUTweakII and restarted after installing, now I have no graphics output and I keep getting post code d6 on my MSI x370 motherboard even with my GTX1080 installed. No clue how to proceed, I'm attempting to flash my BIOS to latest once I get home. Using an MSI X370 Titanium

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you might be having issues with your graphics card and GPUteak.. If they can't play together remove one of them.

- Unmount your graphics card, and plug your monitor to your on board
  card. Try to boot the computer and uninstall GPUTweak. Shut it down.
- Mount your graphics card again and try to boot.

Looking up your post code [D6] I should think your PSU might not be able to provide enough power for your graphics card when using GPUtweak as it likely enables more demanding powerstates thus maxing out your PSU's maximum output.

- Try a new PSU with higher wattage

Comment: Using a 750w PSU, and my Ryzen doesn't have an iGPU